# Angularjs app not triggered

Tags: angularjs

For some reason my Angular site isn't working. I've included all the files. but for some reason angular isn't triggered to do something.

This is how my `index.html` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngTest">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Test</h2>

    <ng-view></ng-view>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/home/HomeCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All included scripts return `200` in the developer console, so I'm sure they are loaded fine.

Then my `app.js` looks like this:

```
window.app = angular.module('ngTest', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$provide', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $provide) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Home', { templateUrl: '/app/views/home/Home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Login' });
}]);
```

The `HomeCtrl.js` simply looks lke this:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    init();
    function init() {
        alert('aaa');
    }
}]);
```

And the `Home.html` only contains a piece of text.

Then when I navigate to: `localhost/#Home` then I expect it to load my `Home.html` in the `ng-view` tag. But that's not happening. It only loads my `index.html` but no angular code seems to be triggered.

Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
angular.module('ngTest', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngAnimate']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$provide', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $provide) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/Home', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/home/Home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Login'
    });
}]);

You could do that for controlers :

angular.module('ngTest.controllers', []);//Declare controllers


angular.module('ngTest.controllers').
controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    init();
    function init() {
        alert('aaa');
    }
```

}]);

By the way, with `html5Mode(true)` your path will be *localhost/Home*.

Comment: This does trigger my controller, but with the error that `app` is undefined. Which makes sense, because `window.app` isn't defined anymore like I had before. So how should I build my controller code then when using your method? -- What bothers me though is that even Angular does something like `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);`. So that seems to be the correct/preferable way of creating the code?

Comment: I edited my answer and added controler call.
Actually, maybe your issue was related to use window.app instead 'var app'.